# How to create UIBarButton to call UITapGestureRecognizer function using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitapgesturerecognizer

My scenario, I am trying to implement `UIBarButton` click to call below two `functions`. Below code already working for `view` `tab and pan` but now I am changing button click to call below two functions. How to modify below `code`?

```
@objc
    func handleCardTap(recognzier:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognzier.state {
        case .ended:
            animateTransitionIfNeeded(state: nextState, duration: 0.9)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    @objc
    func handleCardPan (recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            startInteractiveTransition(state: nextState, duration: 0.9)
        case .changed:
            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.cardViewController.handleArea)
            var fractionComplete = translation.y / cardHeight
            fractionComplete = cardVisible ? fractionComplete : -fractionComplete
            updateInteractiveTransition(fractionCompleted: fractionComplete)
        case .ended:
            continueInteractiveTransition()
        default:
            break
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to call both these tap gesture recognizer functions from a `UIBarButtonItem`, your best bet is to create a custom view bar button item and add gesture recognizers to that custom view. Something like this would work:

```
let tapGestureView = UIView() // initialize & size this as you need
tapGestureView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(action: #selector(handleCardTap(_:)), target: self))
tapGestureView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(action: #selector(handleCardPan(_:)), target: self))
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: tapGestureView)
```

Here are some additional resources for [UITapGestureRecognizers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624211-init)
and [UIBarButtonItems](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617151-init). It seems a bit odd to set up 2 different tap gestures for the same view, though, and one of them being a pan action (at least by name) seems odd, but this is how you'd accomplish that!

Comment: Thank you so much @BHendricks. I will try and update you here.

Comment: ..its not showing bar button. May i know how to do this? Could you please update your answer?

Comment: You'll need to properly set up the bar button you're trying to work with, in this case the `UIView` needs a size defined (or things put in it) for it to show up. My answer is for your original question, if you have further questions you should open new questions for them.